# What is the meaning of Google Calendar API Delete 410 error

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to delete an event from one of my Google calendars using the Java API.  They code looks like:

```
calendarService.events().delete( calendarId , eventId ).execute();
```

When I do so, I get the error:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 410 Gone
DELETE https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@group.calendar.google.com/events/jm1gamo1cj3dm68bidsaufffdg
{
  "code" : 410,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Resource has been deleted",
    "reason" : "deleted"
  } ],
  "message" : "Resource has been deleted"
}
```

I can't figure out what the message is telling me.

Is it saying the event wasn't found?  If so, the wording seems odd - why wouldn't it say "not found".

Or, is it saying it was deleted previously where the event is **marked** as deleted (a logical deletion) but still remains in the system (thus it knows it was previously deleted) possibly queued for a physical deletion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Calendar API documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/errors#410_gone):

> `410: Gone`
>
> `SyncToken` or `updatedMin` parameters are no longer valid. *This error can also occur if a request attempts to delete an event that has already been deleted.*

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "deleted",
    "message": "Resource has been deleted"
   }
  ],
  "code": 410,
  "message": "Resource has been deleted"
 }
}
```

So, if you already deleted an event and you try to delete it again, you will most likely be getting this error message.

#### Reference

- [Calendar API Handling API Errors](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/errors).

Comment: Thanks!  I missed that bit.  Now on to figure out how the event was previously deleted.